# Play music from Server

Tags: server, music, webserver, music-player

I want to configure Ubuntu Server to play music from the same server, with a couple of points:

- It will not do streaming. It will play the music from the server to the speakers connected to it.
- It will be controlled by an app that offers a webpage to connect to the music list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPD will be able to do this, and also streaming if you so desired. The setup can be a bit tricky but once you figure it out it's not too bad.

Once you have MPD setup, [handy wiki page here](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Configuration#Initial_Configuration), I'd look into [client175](http://code.google.com/p/client175) for an interface, it has a nice and pretty fully featured web interface for MPD.